# How to perform Signup and Sign In Api using Django for Android

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, backend

I am new to back end development. I am using the `Django` framework for implementing the back end of my Android application. My app has "create account" and login screens. How can I create API for that using `Django`?
Someone, please help!

Comment: Read the two doc [first](https://codeburst.io/building-an-api-with-django-rest-framework-and-class-based-views-75b369b30396) and [second](https://medium.com/quick-code/token-based-authentication-for-django-rest-framework-44586a9a56fb) , Which helps you registration user, and token base authentication which is used for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

you can use django-rest-auth for using django core authentication process

https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html